# Finding a Polynomial Root

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I need to solve a problem which involves finding the root of the following polynomial:

```
(l) = [(w.n.l + (1+r)k - k1 - g)^(-(1/sigma))].w.n - gamma.(l)^(1/phi),
```

The problem is that the monotonicity of `f(l)` depends on the set of given parameters `(w,n,r,k,k1,g,sigma,phi)`.

When `[(1+r)k - k1 -g] < 0`, then `f(l)` is not monotonic, having more than one root. Someone can help me to find all these roots on Matlab?

Comment: are you running into problems using matlab? have you tried using the symbolic math toolbox?